# How to automatically train the Knowledge Base (QnAMaker Service)?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

In the QnA Maker Service provided by the Microsoft's Cognitive Services, we can train our KB (Knowledge Base) by manually inserting the QnA pairs.

Is there a way to automate this process so that we can always keep our KB up-to-date please? There is an API documentation but i cannot find one for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

The new [V2.0 APIs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa) let you programmatically manage your knowledge base. Now you can do the following with the APIs:

- Create knowledge base
- Delete knowledge base
- Update knowledge base
- Download knowledge base
- Publish knowledge base

Comment: I have a full article with C# code here: http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/1023/Programmatically-Updating-A-QnA-Maker-Service-Using-the-QnA-Maker-API

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bot that will automatically update the QnA Maker KB. Currently supports Add operation, where you add QnA pairs in the KB and publish it. I used QnA Maker client library using C#. You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/quickstart-sdk?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

On providing the qna pairs by the user, I am calling the Client library.

```
if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Here are the details you provided."), cancellationToken);

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Questions - "), cancellationToken);

            for (int i = 0; i < QnAData.QuestionPhrase.Count; i++)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(QnAData.QuestionPhrase[i]), cancellationToken);
            }


            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Answer - " + (string)stepContext.Values["Answer"]), cancellationToken);

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Please wait while I update your Knowledge Base."), cancellationToken);

            var authoringURL = $"https://{Configuration["ResourceName"]}.cognitiveservices.azure.com";

            // <AuthorizationAuthor>
            var client = new QnAMakerClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(Configuration["Key"]))
            { Endpoint = authoringURL };
            // </AuthorizationAuthor>

            QnAClient.UpdateKB(client, Configuration["KnowledgeBaseId"], (string)stepContext.Values["Answer"]).Wait();
            QnAClient.PublishKb(client, Configuration["KnowledgeBaseId"]).Wait();

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("I have added your qna pair in the Knowledge Base. Thank you for using QnA Updator Bot Service."));

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Request Not Confirmed."));
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
```

You can find the full article here : https://jd-bots.com/auto-updater-qna-maker-kb-bot/.

You can watch the video to check the outcome of the bot : https://youtu.be/nSGgph_RXiE.